# Ugly ragged fonts in pdflatex and lualatex prints

Tags: fonts, fontspec, printing

I recently had to print out one of my LaTeX documents and was surprised by the bad quality of the prints in comparison to standard Word or PDF prints. The font produced in the prints by pdflatex or LuaLaTeX is a little 'ragged' around the edges, however the digital PDFs seem to be fine.

The picture shows the problem, especially in the words 'over' and 'dog'.

1. LuaLaTeX, 12pt article, fontspec
2. pdfLaTeX (latexmk), 12pt article, T1 fontenc
3. Standard PDF created by Word 2016 as a comparison

Any suggestions what the problem could be?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Perhaps the font format embedded in the PDF is different (Type 1 versus Type 1C possibly?), and there's some difference in what gets sent to the printer. You could run `pdffonts` (or the Windows equivalent), and/or include sample PDFs so that someone else could take a look.

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the code responsible for the output. For example, we don't know how you've defined your fonts. Obviously, that output is not just the result of switching to `T1` encoding or loading `fontspec`, as neither CMR nor LMR looks like that. The kerning would concern me in all three outputs, but that's a different matter. Looks like a Times clone of some kind. But the chances of all three samples using the same clone are slim.

Comment: Open the PDF in any decent PDF reader. Then, in its Porperties, look for fonts. What fonts are embedded? Be exact: Not just the font name, but the entirety of what is embedded. As other noted, the reason is almost certainly because something in your document (or TeX installation) used non-scalable fonts.